# What does high CD4 level means?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, immunity

I was going through [this webpage](http://www.nii.res.in/research/vineeta-bal) and I found the following lines:

> We hypothesised that despite unimodal distribution of CD4 co-receptor on naïve CD4 T cells they are not homogenous in their function.By testing naïve CD4 population from mice and humans expressing highest and lowest (~10%) levels of CD4 in a variety of functional assays we find that indeed naïve CD4 cells with high CD4 levels respond much better to activation and survive more easily post-activation.

Now what does "CD4 level" means? How is the CD4 receptors distribution obtained? With repect to the value of which feature is it obtained?(If you are not able to understand the last question, let me know, I will try to explain more in details)

Comment: In this case, I would email the corresponding author of the article and request that they provide you with a definition of what High means. A scientific text should not use vague qualitative descriptions like that. They should provide you with at the very least a range of what they classify as high, low, and normal expression of CD4 receptors.

Comment: and what does just CD4 level mean??

Comment: The number of CD4 co receptors on a CD4 T-Cell... when the T-Cell Receptor binds to MHC II the interaction is stabilized by the CD4 coreceptor. It binds to the side of the MHC II receptor on the Antigen Presenting Cell and greatly increases the efficiency of binding. I thought with the second question that you understood that CD4 refers to plasma membrane receptors on the surface of helper T-Cells.

Comment: okay okay, it is my fault actually, i was not able to frame it properly

Comment: @AMR it looks like the answer is in the question - "high" and "low" were defined as the 10% on either side of the curve...

Comment: @MattDMo The problem is that they do not defining what that 10% refers to. Are they talking about the top and bottom ten percent of cells that have been FACS sorted for CD4 receptor levels or is it like you suggested +/- 10% range above and below the mean that differs the highest number of receptors on a T-cell surface to the lowest numbers. I initially thought that Rishika understood what they meant by CD4 levels and suggested the author contact to clarify, but I think that their question was more basic, that CD4 was referring to the corecptor in the plasma membrane.